# What is Equivalent of Google GCM in Blackberry?

Tags: php, android, blackberry, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) to send data from server to Android Devices. It is working properly , Now i have to do same for Blackberry devices .

I have already googled a lot, but not getting solution.

I am working with PHP code in this project, Need some Suggestions to complete this task.

Comment: Have you tried searching here? There are quite a few questions regarding [push notifications for Blackberry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blackberry+push-notification).

Comment: try this.. http://urbanairship.com/.. But we have to pay for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlackBerry Push Services](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/push_service_overview.html) may be the solution that you are seeking as it provides a seamless connection between content providers and push-enabled BlackBerry devices.

For server side development, there is first the "Standalone option" that provides control and flexibility to making push messages.  It is an agnostic back-end system solution therefore can integrate into existing systems that are using either PHP,.NET,JAVA, etc technologies.  With this approach, [Push Access Protocol](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/51382/) ([PAP](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/51382/pap_messages_implemented_1254561_11.jsp)) will need to be implemented along with other items such as subscription management.

There is also the secondary approach using the "[Push Service SD](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/push_service_sdk.html)K" which provides two types of options that include client/server side samples to reduce complexity.
"Push Essentials" tier in the Push Service SDK option allows for user subscription, user management, push message validation, and managing result notifications.  While the "Push Plus" tier in the Push Service SDK option encompasses "Push Essential" features, it also allows storing push requests so if your push solution receives a result notification, it can then perform status queries locally.  "Push Plus" as well allows knowledge of if an end user has received a push message.  Both tiers of the Push Service SDK require a JAVA implementation as java encapsulates PAP API thus removing the need to implement a PAP protocol.

Depending on your requirements and how you want to design your application you can use either the Standalone or Push Service SDKs approach.

Hope these suggestions help!